# How to set user specific session timeout in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, session-timeout

I am trying to set user specific session timeout in a asp.net core application. I have used below code to set the timeout from ConfigureServices in Startup class.

```
services.AddSession(options => options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(8));
```

However, this is applied to all users of the application. My requirement is to add it from the controller if the user trying to login is a special user.